# jquery validate not validating custom rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to validate a form with [JQuery Validate plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate). I need to validate for brazilian phones, but my form is not being validated. It's only checking if the field phone is required, but not it's not checking my custom rule. 
How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
<form action="/account/payment/create" name="payment_form" id="payment_form">

  <input placeholder="Telefone" type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control input-lg m-b" required>
  <input type ="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Pagar </input>

</form>

<script>
jQuery.validator.addMethod('celular', function (value, element) {
        value = value.replace("(","");
        value = value.replace(")", "");
        value = value.replace("-", "");
        value = value.replace(" ", "").trim();
        if (value == '0000000000') {
            return (this.optional(element) || false);
        } else if (value == '00000000000') {
            return (this.optional(element) || false);
        } 
        if (["00", "01", "02", "03", , "04", , "05", , "06", , "07", , "08", "09", "10"].indexOf(value.substring(0, 2)) != -1) {
            return (this.optional(element) || false);
        }
        if (value.length < 10 || value.length > 11) {
            return (this.optional(element) || false);
        }
        if (["6", "7", "8", "9"].indexOf(value.substring(2, 3)) == -1) {
            return (this.optional(element) || false);
        }
        return (this.optional(element) || true);
    }, 'Informe um celular válido'); 



    $("#payment_form").validate({
            rules: {

                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    celular: true
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you first taken a look in the error console? THere's stuff in this code that I don't think will run in the first place, like the `, ,`

Comment: Have some `console.log(...)` statement printed inside the `addMethod(...`
So that you might know whether the method is getting triggered.